# Изменить код с# на реализацию с++

Tags: c#, c++

```
        double[][] result = new double[rows][];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
            result[i] = new double[7];
```

Comment: @user339967 ответ на вопрос можно легко найти в интернете. Гуглите: "Динамический многомерный массив c++"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то это должно выглядеть так:

```
int rows = 100;
double result[rows][7];
```

Comment: вероятно `double **result = new double[rows *7];`